# How do I update the contentSize of a React Native ScrollView containing a custom label?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have need to create a custom UILabel in order to display some HTML. I am taking this HTML in and creating an attributed string that I then put into a UILabel.

However, when I place this UILabel in a ScrollView, the contentSize remains 16, even when there are multiple paragraphs of text - I take that to be the default height of the UILabel? The result is that while the scroll view can be scrolled somewhat, it always rubber-bands back to the top.

Here is a sample of the custom UILabel:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [self setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToWindow
{
  [self sizeToFit];
}

- (void)setHtml:(NSString *)html
{
  NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSAttributedString *body = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                              options:@{
                                                                NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                              }
                                                   documentAttributes:nil
                                                                error:nil];
  [self setAttributedText:body];
}
```

And it is used as such:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <HtmlLabel text="<p>lorem ipsum... </p>"
    />
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Should I be manually updating the contentSize of the ScrollView inside my native view? Should I be using something like RCTTextView instead of rolling my own so that I can rely on the default React Native layout?

Thanks!